# SQL Filter by date for all tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I want to run an SQL query involving multiple tables only for the entries created before a specific date. Instead of filtering tables by date one by one, is there a way to filter the whole database? I want something like a time machine for a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.created_at < now() || table2.created_at < now();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Simon. Your solution requires filtering all tables one by one. My query is very long and includes many sub-selects. So, I am looking for a more straightforward solution.